# Customize the captions of tables

Tags: tables, captions, floatrow

I'm a little disperse between packages `caption`, `floatrow`, I'd customize the captions of my tables, but at the same time, I would like the figures captions to remain unchanged.

- How can I left align the captions?
- How I can customize the space between caption and table?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,twoside,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font={it,footnotesize},labelfont={bf,sc,small},figurename=Fig.,tablename=Tab.]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}   %\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
%\setlength\abovecaptionskip{0.5cm}
%\setlength\belowcaptionskip{0.5cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!b]
\begin{center}
\small{
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{3cm}@{}*{6}{X@{}}}
\toprule 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{couleur primaire} & \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{couleur secondaire} \\
\cmidrule[.8pt](r{10pt}){2-4} \cmidrule[.8pt]{5-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & rouge & vert & bleu &  jaune & magenta & cyan \\
\midrule[1pt] 
composition & R & V & B & RV & RB & VB \\ 
perméabilité& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4  & 7  & 3 \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}}
\end{center}
\caption{thermal conductivity}
\label{tab-CT1}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Just to clarify: When you refer to legends (of tables), do you have their `caption`s in mind? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

By using the `caption` package you can set the aspect of your tables and figures separately, like this:

```
  \captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={sc},textfont={sl}}
  \captionsetup[table]{labelfont={sc},textfont={sl}}
```

See section 2.3 (and actually, the whole document) of the [`caption` package documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) for how to further customize your captions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way.

Add

```
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false,justification=raggedright,position=top,skip=50pt}
```

in the preamble and **don't load** `floatrow` since the last two options are not compatible with it (adjust `50pt` to your needs).

Then move the `\caption` at the beginning of the table.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,twoside,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font={it,footnotesize},labelfont={bf,sc,small},figurename=Fig.,tablename=Tab.]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false,justification=raggedright,position=top,skip=50pt}
%\usepackage{floatrow}
%\floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}
%\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
%\setlength\abovecaptionskip{0.5cm}
%\setlength\belowcaptionskip{0.5cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!b]
\caption{thermal conductivity}
\label{tab-CT1}
\begin{center}
\small{
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{3cm}@{}*{6}{X@{}}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{couleur primaire} & \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{couleur secondaire} \\
\cmidrule[.8pt](r{10pt}){2-4} \cmidrule[.8pt]{5-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & rouge & vert & bleu &  jaune & magenta & cyan \\
\midrule[1pt]
composition & R & V & B & RV & RB & VB \\
perméabilité& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4  & 7  & 3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}}
\end{center}
%\caption{thermal conductivity}
%\label{tab-CT1}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

Note that in this way you have the caption left-aligned with the text (you cannot notice any difference since your table is `\linewidth`-wide).

In case you want the caption left-aligned with the table you have to use the command `\captionbox` as in the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,twoside,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font={it,footnotesize},labelfont={bf,sc,small},figurename=Fig.,tablename=Tab.]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false,justification=raggedright,position=top,skip=50pt}
%\usepackage{floatrow}
%\floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}
%\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
%\setlength\abovecaptionskip{0.5cm}
%\setlength\belowcaptionskip{0.5cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!b]
\centering\small
\captionbox{thermal conductivity\label{tab-CT1}}{%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{3cm}@{}*{6}{X@{}}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{couleur primaire} & \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{couleur secondaire} \\
\cmidrule[.8pt](r{10pt}){2-4} \cmidrule[.8pt]{5-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & rouge & vert & bleu &  jaune & magenta & cyan \\
\midrule[1pt]
composition & R & V & B & RV & RB & VB \\
perméabilité& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4  & 7  & 3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}}
%\caption{thermal conductivity}
%\label{tab-CT1}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```